# Rearranging a string based on a specific requirement to return a list of strings

Tags: python, list

Hi there so I am looking to build this python function with simple things like def, find etc. so far I know how to get the first part of the code.

Given a string such as `"HELLODOGMEMEPAPA"`, I will need to return a list that gives me three things:

- Everything before the word dog which i will denote as `before_dog`
- The word dog and three letters after it denoted as `dog_3letters`
- Everything after the `dog_3letters` which i will denote as `everything_after`

The list will be in the form `[before_dog,dog_3letters,everything_after]`.

So given a string such as `"HELLODOGMEMEPAPA"` I will need to return the list `["HELLO", "DOGMEM", "EPAPA"]` or a string like `"HEYWHATDOGDODOD"` I will need to return `["HEYWHAT","DOGDOD","OD"]`.

This is what I have so far:

```
def split_list(words):
    # declare the list
    lst = []
    # find the first position
    first_pos=words.find("DOG")
    # find the first_pos
    first = words [0:first_pos]
    lst.append(first)
    return lst
```

Comment: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_r8oN6yZSyJ_0.py

Answer (score 1):

Use slices to find the expected substrings, like this:

```
def split_word(s, word):
    i = s.find(word)
    n = len(word)
    before = s[:i]
    word3  = s[i:i+n+3]
    after  = s[i+n+3:]
    return [before, word3, after]
```

For example:

```
split_word('HELLODOGMEMEPAPA', 'DOG')
=> ['HELLO', 'DOGMEM', 'EPAPA']
split_word('HEYWHATDOGDODOD', 'DOG')
=> ['HEYWHAT', 'DOGDOD', 'OD']
```

Comment: won't work since I have to input the string into the shell and can't assume that s will always be HELLODOGMEPAPA,def split_list(words):
    # declare the list
    lst = []
    i = words.find('DOG')
    n = len('DOG')
    before_dog = words[:i]
    dog_3letters = words[i:n+3]
    everything_after = words[i+n+3:]
    lst.append(before_dog)
    lst.append(dog_3letters)
    lst.append(everything_after)
    return lst

Comment: @KirusanS ok, I wrote a more general solution that takes into account any input word, check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use `find` to get the position of `DOG` and then :

```
>>> s
=> 'HELLODOGMEMEPAPA'

>>> pos_dog = s.lower().find('DOG')
>>> pos_dog
=> 5

>>> before_dog = s[:pos_dog]
>>> before_dog
=> 'HELLO'

>>> dog_3letters = s[pos_dog : pos_dog+6]
>>> dog_3letters
=> 'DOGMEM'

>>> everything_after = s[pos_dog+6 : ]
>>> everything_after
=> 'EPAPA'

>>> [before_dog, dog_3letters, everything_after]
=> ['HELLO', 'DOGMEM', 'EPAPA']
```

Comment: Sure, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an obvious use of a regexp, see example code below

```
>>> import re
>>> teststr="HEYWHATDOGDODOD"
>>> x=re.search('(.*)(DOG...)(.*)',teststr)
>>> x.groups()
('HEYWHAT', 'DOGDOD', 'OD')
```